# reading an alphanumeric text file and trying to store to a list or array

Tags: java

I am using `scanner.usedelimiter("[^0-9|,]")` this pattern to avoid alphabets from a text file.then using hasNext and next() methods to store to a string and then list but list is adding additional o and whitespaces.

I am using Scanner class to read a text file and extract only numbers from that text file

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("123.txt");
sc.useDelimiter("[^0-9|,|-]");
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String s = null;
    s = sc.next();
    list.add(s.replaceAll("\\s+",""));
}
```

Actual file has data

```
Class   Student Details
1          total 25 students with 80% pass
2A - 3B          total 90 students with 70% pass
4A - 5B         total 69 students with 80% pass 10 distinction
```

Expected Output

```
1 25 80
2 3 90 70
4 5  69 80 10
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: output is coming as below

Comment: 0100025008020030090 adding additional zeros and empty spaces to the list

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: Don't use numbers are your delimiter. Use linebreaks as your delimiter, then you can simply regex replace every that's not a digit with a space `s.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ")`

Answer (score 0):

With a `123.txt` file like so:

```
Class   Student Details
1          total 25 students with 80% pass
2A - 3B          total 90 students with 70% pass
4A - 5B         total 69 students with 80% pass 10 distinction
```

You could split each line using a regex to obtain only the numbers:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> classDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        File file = new File("123.txt");
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            scanner.nextLine(); // Skip header row
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                List<String> classNumbers = Arrays.asList(line.split("[^\\d]+"));
                classDetails.add(classNumbers.stream()
                                             .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
                                             .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (List<Integer> classNumbers : classDetails) {
            System.out.println(classNumbers);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 25, 80]
[2, 3, 90, 70]
[4, 5, 69, 80, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution: instead of using Scanner, you can import the `java.nio` package and in particular the `Files` class:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
```

Once you obtained the list of all lines of the file you can iterate over them and replace every not a digit with a space:

```
String s = line.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code base with java 8 features.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String fileName = "D:\\data\\123.txt";

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

         stream.map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " "))
               .filter(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty())
               .forEach(System.out::println);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```